# Centrar formularios materialize

Tags: css, css3, materialize

tengo problemas al centrar verticalmente el formulario usando materialize css, he probado usando los helper de la documentación como valing-wrapper pero no lo consigo.

```
    <div class="col z-depth-6 card-panel">
  <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <div class="row valign-wrapper">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">perm_identity</i>
        <input id="user" type="text" name="user">
        <label for="user">User</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">lock_outline</i>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn col s12 blue" name="login">
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este es un problema que ya se ha [reportado con anterioridad](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2700). Sucede que es necesario que la clase `.valign-wrapper` tenga una altura definida para que así las propiedades se apliquen correctamente.

Esta característica se da específicamente por la propiedad `display: flex` que entra en conflicto con la altura:

> Para asegurar un tamaño mínimo por defecto de los elementos flexibles,
>   usa `min-width: auto` y/o `min-height: auto`. Para los elementos
>   flexibles, el valor de atributo auto calcula la mínima anchura/altura
>   del elemento para que no sea menor que la anchura/altura de su
>   contenido, garantizando que el elemento es mostrado suficientemente
>   grande como para que se vea su contenido.

Puedes usar la unidad `vh` con valor `100` la cual hace referencia al alto total del [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Sizing_items_in_CSS#Viewport_units).

```css
.valign-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="valign-wrapper">
  <div class="col z-depth-6 card-panel">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">perm_identity</i>
          <input id="user" type="text" name="user">
          <label for="user">User</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">lock_outline</i>
          <input id="password" type="password" name="password">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn col s12 blue" name="login">
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Consulta más información sobre los elementos flexibles, su composición y posicionamiento en [este link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Usando_las_cajas_flexibles_CSS).

PD: Si también deseas centrar tu contenedor horizontalmente, puedes usar cualquiera de [estas dos alternativas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009924/).

Comment: Perfecto, era justo lo que necesitaba, para centrarlo, con un margin:auto me ha bastado.